# TinyMCE: Automatic add style attribute on link creation

Tags: coding-style, attributes, hyperlink, tinymce, creation

In TinyMCE, I need to add a in-line style attribute on link creation. The reason is that Google Mail doesn't support  tags in a newsletter.

One solution can be "advlink". But who would explain to our user...that he must add css code in a new link...bad solution.

There must be a simpler, user-friendly way, but i can't find it. Is there an option that i can tell the plugin to add automatic style-attributes to a link?

//EDIT
Ok, i think another solution can be, if i can add anchor to 'style_formats'. But an anchor is not supported in 'style_formats'...someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may write an own plugin which adds the inline style element to links.

An easier approch is to put the necessary code into the setup config paramter.

Comment: Hey, thanke for the answer.

With setup confi parameter do you mean:

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'mode': "textareas",
...
}

?

I think, to write a plugin is to much for this problem..

Comment: i do not know which platform you use, the syntax differs slightly, but what you showed my looks like its the right place

Comment: Oh sorry, i use django with django-tinymce.

What should i write in this configuration? on tinymce.com doku i can't find something that helps..

Comment: you would need to add a handler which is listening on DomChange events. once it gets fired you check all links in the editor and give them the inline attribute if necessary